# Работа с CSS через javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой элемент:

```
<div class="EventMainBlock">
    <div class="TypeOfEventBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventCheckBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventStatusBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventDescriptionBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventDateBlock"></div>
    <div class="EventActionBlock"></div>
</div>
```

Из себя он представляет таблицу, но высота его под элементов не одинакова. Как изменить css свойство высоты для данных под элементов? При этом если элементов много на странице, то document.getElementById сработает один раз, то есть измениться только один элемент.

Comment: А как расположены ячейки таблицы?

Comment: float:left, тобишь одна за одной в родителе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я не ошибся, то вам нужно проэмулировать одинаковую высоту флоат элементов, перед тем как навешивать ява скрипт почитайте про [inline-block](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/pozitsionirovanie/inline-block-simple-property-for-complex-tasks.html) - одинаковые колонки (точнее высота останеться прежней, просто они будут подстраиваться под контент), если это не помогает, то вот небольшой скрипт, который собирает нужные элементы, находит самое большое значение высоты, и присваивает его всем элементам, вам надо только разобраться с тем, чтобы когда много элементов скрипт высчитывал высоту только у элементов из одного ряда (сколько их там в ряду у вас я не знаю)

```
var divs = divsBox.getElementsByTagName('div');
var height = []
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
    height.push(divs[i].clientHeight)
}
var maxHeight = height[0];
for(i=1;i<height.length-1;i++){
    if(height[i]>maxHeight){
        maxHeight = height[i]
    }
}
for(i=0;i<divs.length;i++){
    divs[i].style.height = maxHeight + 'px'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementById('MainBlock')
var elems = div.getElementsByTagName('*')
for(var i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
      elems[i].style.height=...
}
```

Не забудьте дать ID родительскому элементу